# Setting a field by id?

Tags: java

I receive objects from a network.

I need to set the value of specific fields. However, I want to avoid using reflection every time to lookup the field.

Ideally, I would want to do something like:

```
int fieldNo = Something.getFieldID("numStairs",SomeClass.class); //do this only once
SomeClass s = (SomeClass)myObject;
s.setField(fieldNo,null);
```

Basically, at first, I look up the id's of the fields I need, then I set the value without having to dynamically perform reflection to access the field every time.

I am wondering if something like this is possible in Java.

If not, what might be an efficient way given a fieldName String, and an Object (asserting that the field does exist), to set the value of that field to null (assuming also you know the field is nullable).

Comment: What is it about using reflection that bothers you? It's the tool for this job, really.

Comment: Why not just define two helper methods for getting and setting a field, hiding the reflection code within? Just do whatever you would do with reflection and put it in a helper function.

Comment: @RealSkeptic Im real skeptical about the performance of reflection. I need this to be fast.

Comment: Well, benchmark it properly, see where you get bottlenecks, and try to optimize around them. There is no way to dynamically access fields except through reflection, but you may be able to cache `Field` objects, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My version below.

SomeClass

```
public class SomeClass {

    private Integer numStairs;

    public SomeClass(Integer numStairs) {
        this.numStairs = numStairs;
    }

    public Integer getNumStairs() {
        return numStairs;
    }
}
```

Main

```
public class Main {

    private static final Map<Class, Field> cache = new HashMap<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass x = new SomeClass(12345);
        //Testing speed
        System.out.println("Test 1");
        int repeats = 10000000;
        long count = 0;
        long t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++) {
            setField(x, i);
            if (x.getNumStairs() == i) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        long t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("\tCount = " + count);
        System.out.println("\tTime = " + (t2 - t1));
        System.out.println("Test 2");
        count = 0;
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeats; i++) {
            setField2(x, i);
            if (x.getNumStairs() == i) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        t2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("\tCount = " + count);
        System.out.println("\tTime = " + (t2 - t1));
    }

    public static void setField(Object o, Integer value) {
        try {
            Field f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("numStairs");
            f.setAccessible(true);
            f.set(o, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void setField2(Object o, Integer value) {
        try {
            Field f = cache.get(o.getClass());
            if (f == null) {
                f = o.getClass().getDeclaredField("numStairs");
                f.setAccessible(true);
                cache.put(o.getClass(), f);
            }
            f.set(o, value);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Test 1
    Count = 10000000
    Time = 4092
Test 2
    Count = 10000000
    Time = 1003
```